# What is the best way to append custom message to the output when pytest.raises fails?

Tags: python, pytest

What I'm aiming at is - if I ran the following test:

```
def test_func():
    with pytest.raises(APIError):
        func()
```

and the func() did not raise APIError - I want to get custom message to the output, e.g. "No APIError caught"

Pytest had a feature specifically for this:

```
with raises(SomeError, message="Custom message here"):
    pass
```

https://docs.pytest.org/en/4.2.1/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions
but for some reason it didn't make it to further versions (current is 6.0.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replicate this behavior using the [`pytest.fail`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-fail) function after the function you expect to raise an exception, since that will only run if an exception is not raised. The [deprecation notice](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#message-parameter-of-pytest-raises) explains the reasoning for its removal, and offers this alternate approach:

```py
import pytest

def func():
    return

def test_func():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        func()
        pytest.fail("Oh no!")
```

```sh
$ pytest test.py

collected 1 item

test.py F                                                                                                                                                                                                   [100%]

==================================================================================================== FAILURES =====================================================================================================
____________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_func ____________________________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_func():
        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
            func()
>           pytest.fail("Oh no!")
E           Failed: Oh no!

test.py:9: Failed
============================================================================================= short test summary info =============================================================================================
FAILED test.py::test_func - Failed: Oh no!
================================================================================================ 1 failed in 0.16s ================================================================================================
```

Comment: Could you please clarify how did you find this solution? I was googling and browsing documentation, but somehow never found this. Probably my research process is flawed.

Comment: @RomanPonomaryov in this case, since it's a feature that previously existed but was removed, the [changelog](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/changelog.html) is the best place to look (search "pytest.raises" on the page until you find the release where it was removed, which turns out to be [5.1.0](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/changelog.html#pytest-5-1-0-2019-08-15)). Pytest is a particularly well-documented library, and tends to include pretty detailed explanations of the reasons features are removed, as well as code samples to work around the removal.